# What does "!!! Unknown header type 7f" error means?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, xorg

I bought a new laptop, and I can't enable discrete graphic card.

The output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display' terminal command:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon APU A4-6000 with R2 Graphics]
Subsystem: Dell Device 0658
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8500M Series] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx
```

when I triedcommand lspci -v it showed this output:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8500M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
!!! Unknown header type 7f
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx
```

I tried command:
    sudo amdconfig --initial --force --adapter=al

But then Ubuntu didn't load at all, and I needed to use backup of xorg.conf.

Please, help me to turn on my graphics card. I've been trying to fix this stuff for a few days already.
Evgeniy.

Comment: Don't know if you fixed this already, but you can check this out: [amd gpu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/841431/switching-to-the-amd-gpu/) and [paradox thread](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/stellaris-graphics-and-linux-wine.976919/#post-22004431) Hope this helps. I got it working... sort of... maybe you have more luck.